# Finding element containing string and replace sibling element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have a site and I only have classes to work with to isolate the element I wish to edit. I need to find an element that contains a certain string within the html and replace one of it's siblings html. Anyways, here's the code I've got:

```
if((".user.info").html().indexOf(vaUID[index]) >= 0) {
    $("a.user.info").each(function (index2, obj) {
        if($(this).html().indexOf(vaUID[index]) >= 0) {
            $(this).siblings('.registered').html('<div class="registered"><a href=http://www.twitch.tv/'+users[index]+ '>currently streaming' + data.stream.game + '</a></div>');
        }
    });
}
```

here's the starting html:

```
<div class="user first">
    <div class="element_avatar simple small  "><a href="http://www.cnr-clan.com/profile/xxxxxx" data-minitooltip="username"><img src="http://assets-cloud.enjin.com/users/xxxxxx/avatar/small.xxxxxx.png"></a></div>
    <div class="info">
        <a href="http://www.cnr-clan.com/profile/xxxxxx" class="element_username tag-xxxxxx">username</a>
        <span class="nameicons">
            <!--Irrelevant Excess Code-->
        </span>
        <div class="registered">currently browsing</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearing"><!--  --></div>
</div>
```

What I want to end up with:

```
<div class="user first">
    <div class="element_avatar simple small  "><a href="http://www.cnr-clan.com/profile/xxxxxx" data-minitooltip="username"><img src="http://assets-cloud.enjin.com/users/2219573/avatar/small.xxxxxx.png"></a></div>
    <div class="info">
        <a href="http://www.cnr-clan.com/profile/xxxxxx" class="element_username tag-xxxxxx">username</a>
        <span class="nameicons">
            <!--Irrelevant Excess Code-->
        </span>
        <div class="registered"><a href='http://www.twitch.tv/username'>currently streaming gamename</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearing"><!--  --></div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that I have several blocks of code like this with the same class. An example value of vaUID[index] would be xxxxxx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that an easier method would be just to select using a specific value for the href attribute. Here's my resulting javascript:

```
$(".user .info a[href='http://www.cnr-clan.com/profile/" + vaUID[index] + "']").siblings('div.registered')
.html('<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/username/' + users[index] + '">streaming ' + data.stream.game + '</a>');
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest, based on that HTML:

```
// selects the appropriate elements:
$('.user .info a.element_username')
    // filters that collection:
    .filter(function(){
        // retains only those in which this assessment results as true/truthy
        return $.trim($(this).text()) === 'username';
    })
    // searches amongst those retained-elements' sibling for those that match
    // the passed-selector:
    .siblings('div.registered')
    // wraps the contents of those elements with the supplied HTML:
    .wrapInner('<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/username"></a>');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d5xLJ/).

The above `filter()` condition will retain only those elements whose text-content *precisely* matches the `'username'` string ([demo to highlight that problem](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d5xLJ/1/)); to retain those that merely *contain* that string you could either amend the `filter()` to:

```
return $(this).text().indexOf('username') > -1; // this is case-sensitive
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d5xLJ/2/).

Or:

```
return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf('username') > -1; // this is case-insensitive
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d5xLJ/3/).

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`jQuery.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/).

Comment: Thanks for setting me on the right track. I've got this code as my js now, but it still seems to be giving me problems.
`$('.user .info a.element_username')
 .filter(function(){
  return $(this).html().indexOf(vaUID[index]) > -1;
 })
 .siblings('div')
 .html('<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/username/' + users[index] + '">streaming ' + data.stream.game + '</a>');`

Comment: I want to find the correct <a> element by checking the last few digits on the href attribute which I dub a user ID. This code is nested in an .each statement that iterates through User Ids (vaUID[index]), an example would be xxxxxx) and twitch.tv usernames (users[index])